# Windows 10 laptop keeps adapting brightness ("Adaptive Brightness" is disabled)

Tags: windows-10, laptop, brightness

My Windows 10 laptop keeps adapting the brightness of my screen.

I did some research and found that the problem could be the Windows' "adaptive Brightness" feature. I disabled it but kept having the same issue.

So, I did some more research and found that the Intel's "Display Power Saving Technology" could be the issue. So, I disabled it, but I keep having the same problem.

Does anyone know what else can be doing this brightness adaptation. It is starting to become very frustrating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing power plan settings did not work, you need to type ''run'' then type ''services.msc''

Search in the list for ''sensor monitoring service'' right click on it, properties and disable the service, hit apply.

Navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Intel\Display\igfxcui\profiles\media\Brighten Movie and change ProcAmpBrightness to 0

also navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Intel\Display\igfxcui\profiles\media\Darken Movie and change ProcAmpBrightness to 0

Restart.

Comment: Well, I'm using the notebook for a while now since I disabled sensor monitoring service and apparently it worked. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I've looked around the web and there appear to be several possible causes and solutions to this problem depending on your Windows version and hardware. Here's a compilation of how to turn off adaptive brightness.

1. Go to **Power Options** > Display > Enable Adaptive Brightness > Set it to Off in both places

[image]

2. Go to **AMD Catalyst Control Center** > Power > PowerPlay > Uncheck the "Enable Vari-Bright" box

[image]

3. Go to the **Intel Media and Graphics Control Panel** > Power > Disable Intel Power Saving Technology

[image]

4. Go to **Services** > Disable the Adapative Brightness service

[image]

5. In **regedit:**

   Go to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Intel\Display\igfxcui\profiles\media\Brighten Movie** and change ProcAmpBrightness to 0

   Go to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Intel\Display\igfxcui\profiles\media\Darken Movie** and change ProcAmpBrightness to 0

Comment: Github script for Intel Registry Keys DPST https://github.com/orev/dpst-control

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and nothing was working but i figured it out, this is what i did:
go to power options>edit plan setting> change advanced power setting>ATI graphics power setting>ati power play setting.
And then on battery choose maximize performance instead of maximize battery life.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue with my Lenovo laptop, and the way I solved it is as follows:

1. Open any content that is bright, like a blank page.
2. Disconnect the power supply.
3. After a few seconds reconnect power supply.

Next you will notice even when you open a dark content and change back to a white bright content, automatic brightness won't do anything. Brightness will stay the same.