# Whenever I watch a video the screen gets brighter when the cursor disappears

Tags: windows-10, display, brightness

Whenever I watch a video on my Windows 10 system,
the screen gets brighter when the cursor disappears. 
I think it’s an Intel® HD graphics card.

I searched it up and it said to turn off "adaptive brightness",
so I did, but it’s still brightening.

I'll be watching a video and the background is a light gray, when I start watching the video. 
When the cursor, along with the bottom bar disappears, the light gray will turn white; the screen just changes brightness. 
If I move my mouse and the cursor appears again, the screen goes back to normal.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: It sounds like sort of 'video enhance' feature for some graphic cards. Could you provide us some spec of your machine? Like which graphic card it has.

Comment: I think its a intel(R) HD graphics card. I apologize, i'm not great with this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

**First**: we need to ensure the following two points:

1. Download and install the latest graphics driver according to the graphics card or motherboard.
2. Download and install the latest power management drivers according to the model of the machine.

**Second**: Do we use a video player to play video or use a browser to play video?

If we use a video player, we can use other video players, and then check if there is such a issue when playing, if not, it may be the setting issue of this video player. Check if there is a setting like "adaptive brightness" in this video player so that we can adjust the video brightness.

If we use a browser to watch videos, try another browser and see if other browsers have the same issue when playing videos. If only a browser has such a issue, we check the browser settings.

**Third**: If we use all the video players and browsers to watch the video, this issue may be an operating system problem.

We can refer to the articles: [Windows 10 laptop keeps adapting brightness (“Adaptive Brightness” is disabled)](https://superuser.com/questions/1267769/windows-10-laptop-keeps-adapting-brightness-adaptive-brightness-is-disabled)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to Intel® Display Power Saving Technology, here is a Github Script to disable it https://github.com/orev/dpst-control